# How to select day of the year in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date, extract

Given a `sysdate = Sep 13, 2018 13:14:15`,

How do we get/extract that it is 256th day of the year / 257th in leap year from dual?

Answer (score 5):

You could use this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DDD') FROM dual;
```

Refer to [docs_Format_Models](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510) for more informations.